# How can I hide the app bar when it is in the background in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to hide the application bar when when I show the list of applications that are in the background.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUMod.png)

This is the source code

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          title: Text('Hellow World'),
        ),
        body: Center (child: Text('Hello world')));
  }
}
```

I tried to hide the app bar when the app comes in the background and show it when the app comes back to the foreground, but it doesn't work.

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  bool _appbar = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 56),
          child: Visibility(
            visible: _appbar,
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              elevation: 0.0,
              title: Text('Title'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Test'),
        ));
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        setState(() {
          _appbar = true;
        });
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        setState(() {
          _appbar = false;
        });
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update the screen before a snapshot is taken for the 'Recent Apps' view. Add a [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) to your screen to check for state changes.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget with WidgetsBindingObserver{
...
}
```

Add an observer to the current WidgetsBinding instance and a way to remove the observer for when the object is removed from the screen.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  super.dispose();
}
```

Then you can update the screen when the app state is changed. The snapshot of the screen for the 'Recent Apps' is taken before the app is paused. I suggest updating the screen on `inactive` state, because it's the state before `paused`. Then update the screen again when the app state is `resumed`.

```dart
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  switch (state) {
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      // TODO: update screen to add app bar again
      break;
    case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      // TODO: update screen to remove app bar
      break;
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      break;
    case AppLifecycleState.detached:
      break;
  }
}
```

This seems to be an odd use case, but another option here is to just hide the app bar all the time.

Comment: It does not work, in this link they reported the same error https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17551

Comment: Yes, the app bar will still be displayed if it's not removed before the snapshot for the 'Recent apps'. A workaround for this issue is to just update the screen on `inactive` state with the app bar removed from the widgets before a snapshot is taken. With this method, the snapshot displayed won't have an app bar displayed. You can just add the app bar again on `resumed` state.